# How to load multiple textures into the fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture2d

So I'm trying to texture an object in OpenGL and I have two textures that I want to mix together in the fragment shader (rock.tga and grass.tga). My fragment shader:

```
out vec3 color;

in vec2 uv;

uniform sampler2D grasstexture;
uniform sampler2D rocktexture;
```

To load a sampler2D texture here's what I did in my header file in C++:

```
OpenGP::EigenImage<vec3> image;
OpenGP::imread("grass.tga", image);

glGenTextures(0, &_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _tex);

check_error_gl();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
check_error_gl();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F,
             image.cols(), image.rows(), 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image.data());
check_error_gl();
tex_id = glGetUniformLocation(_pid, "grasstexture");
glUniform1i(tex_id, 0);
```

Which loads the grass texture into my fragment shader. Now what I want to know is how do I load in multiple textures. I can't copy the above code twice because one texture is always over-written by the other. So how can I load in multiple textures into the fragment shader?

EDIT: Here's where my `_tex` is declared:

```
    class Mesh{
    protected:
        GLuint _tex;

        GLuint _vpoint;    ///< memory buffer
        GLuint _vnormal;   ///< memory buffer

    public:
        GLuint getProgramID(){ return _pid; }

        void init(){
//code for the textures goes in here
```

Here's my updated code:

```
OpenGP::EigenImage<vec3> image;
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
OpenGP::imread("grass.tga", image);

//glGenTextures(1, &_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _tex);

check_error_gl();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
check_error_gl();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F,
             image.cols(), image.rows(), 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image.data());
check_error_gl();
tex_id = glGetUniformLocation(_pid, "grasstexture");
glUniform1i(tex_id, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
OpenGP::imread("rock.tga", image);

//glGenTextures(0, &_tex);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _tex);

check_error_gl();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
check_error_gl();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB32F,
             image.cols(), image.rows(), 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image.data());
check_error_gl();
tex_id = glGetUniformLocation(_pid, "rocktexture");
glUniform1i(tex_id, 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Opengl hides a lot of its context so you need to keep it in mind. You have three parts of the texture:

- Texture *name* - just an integer, pass it around.
- *Active texture unit* - context thing, set with `GL_TEXTURE0`...
- Texture *target* - for starters GL_TEXTURE_2D is all you need.

Here is what you need to do in order to get a 2d texture working:

1. Create opengl texture *name* with [`glGenTextures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenTextures.xhtml)
2. Set up the texture with following set of actions:

   2.1 Set *active texture unit* with [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)

   2.2 Specify the *target* of the *active texture unit* to which the *named* texture is bound [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml). For this all three texture parts should be "under control".

   2.3 Specify a two-dimensional texture image for the *active texture unit* with [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

   2.4 Set parameters for the *active texture unit* with [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)
3. In order to simultaneously use multiple textures make sure that they have unique *name* and *texture unit*:

   3.1 Set active texture *unit* to 0

   3.2 Bind one *named* texture to active texture *unit*

   3.3 Pass texture *unit* (0) to shader

   3.4 Set active texture unit to 1

   3.5 Bind another *named* texture to active texture *unit*

   3.6 Pass texture *unit* (1) to shader

   ...
4. And when you're done don't forget to delete all named textures with [`glDeleteTextures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteTextures.xhtml)

The order of commands is not the only one possible and the set of commands is not minimal - it is just typical.

---

*Original answer:*

You need to set next active texture like this:

```
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
```

before you bind bind the next texture.
It will also work like:

```
std::vector<std::string> textures = {"grass.tga", "rock.tga"};
for(int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    // create the texture
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I'll update my question with my most up to date code. Basically what's happening is that my rock texture appears as extremely white. I'm not even sure that it is the rock texture or a really bright version of my grass texture. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I also commented out my glGenTextures lines because for some reason that makes my textures not appear at all.